# Web3py Transaction being reverted when using swapExactETHForTokens()

Tags: python, web3py

I am initiating a transaction using the following function.

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=PancakeABI)

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
amountIn = (web3.toWei(0.0001, 'ether'))
start = time.time()
print(web3.toWei('0.002', 'ether'))
toBuyBNBAmount = web3.toWei("0.0002", 'ether')
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
    0, # Here setup the minimum destination token you
       # want to have, you can do some math, or you
       # can put a 0 if you don't want to care
    [spend, contract_id],
    sender_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
).buildTransaction({
    'from': sender_address,
    'value': toBuyBNBAmount, # This is the Token(BNB) amount
                             # you want to Swap from
    'gas': 160000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce
})

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

However, each time my transaction is being reverted:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x021ea258b937ba1575cdf5aed0f49fcad1143f2fc8b25eb8efffdc2347ca6729

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this code line is the problem: `[spend, contract_id]`

You need to use `[tokenA_address, tokenB_address]`.